# How to get https on custom domain Hobby plan Heroku?

Tags: heroku

I just deployed a website to Heroku, and it's on the Hobby plan. I added custom domain, however, it's not `https` anymore.

As I understood from documentation, paid plans have SSL certificates automatically managed.  Does it take some time for it to be changed to `https` or I don't understand something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [set this up](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management) by running

```
heroku certs:auto:enable
```